# Optimizing Sculpting

Tags: sculpting

How should I improve performance in Sculpt Mode?  I have enough RAM, the model has 80 to polygons, modifier multiresistance has 4 units and 20 million polygons.  It's so slow that it's impossible to get anything done, even if I hide part of it.

p.s. I badly know English, I apologize if it is not clearly written.

Comment: 20 Mio polygons are too much. Try to decrease this by 1) decreasing subdivisions 2) unsubdivide 3) remesh ....every computer has it's speed limitations. So try to use only that much details/polygons you need, not as much as you want.

Comment: I noticed a strange feature, I took an object 1.5 k used a multi-resolution of 6 divisions, it turned out 25 million, and it worked quickly.But if you use an object that has 6 million, making 1 division also turns out to be 25 millions, but it works very slowly. why is this happening?